# Incorrect className of child component using babel-plugin-react-css-modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I'm trying to use babel-plugin-react-css-modules in existing React project. Most of components work just fine, however there is a problem with 'passing' style to child components.

I have some parent components like this:

**SearchBlock/index.js**

```
import "./style.scss"
import { SettingsIcon } from "../../Icons"
...
<div styleName='SearchBlock'>
   <SettingsIcon size='17' color='#2991F5' />
</div>
```

**SearcBlock/style.scss**

```
.SearchBlock {
  ...

  .SettingsIcon {
     margin-right: 7px;
  }
...
    }
```

And child components like this

**SettingsIcon/index.js**

```
const SettingsIcon = (props) => {
...
    return (
      <svg
        width={size}
        height={size}
        viewBox='0 0 24 24'
        fill='none'
        xmlns='...'
        className='SettingsIcon'
      >
...
```

So the icon has an appropriate style in different components.

What I get in generated css files:

```
.src-components-Search-SearchBlock-___style__SearchBlock___2MeUy .src-components-Search-SearchBlock-___style__SettingsIcon___3SWQh {
        margin-right: 7px; }
```

Seems correct. However, the child element is rendered like this:

```
<svg ... class="SettingsIcon"><</svg>
```

instead of

```
<svg ... class="src-components-Search-SearchBlock-___style__SettingsIcon___3SWQh"><</svg>
```

I cannot use *styleName* in settingsIcon because webpack throws error without importing at least one stylesheet.

Is there any way to fix this?

---

**My configuration**

webpack.common.js

```
...
    test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                      loader: 'style-loader',
                    },
                    {
                      loader: 'css-loader',
                      options: {
                        modules: {
                          mode: 'local',
                          localIdentName: isProd
                          ? '[hash:base64]'
                          : "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
                        },
                        sourceMap: true,
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        onlyLocals: false,
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      loader: 'postcss-loader',
                      options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      loader: 'sass-loader',
                      options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                      },
                    },
                  ],
            },
...
```

babel.config.js

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

function createReactCssModulesPlugin() {
  return [
    "react-css-modules",
    {
      filetypes: {
        ".scss": {
          syntax: "postcss-scss",
          plugins: [
            "postcss-import-sync2",
            [
              "postcss-nested",
              {
                bubble: ["@include"],
                preserveEmpty: true,
              },
            ],
          ],
        },
      },
      generateScopedName: isProd
        ? '[hash:base64]'
        : "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
      webpackHotModuleReloading: isProd ? false : true,
      exclude: "node_modules",
      handleMissingStyleName: isProd ? "throw" : "warn",
      autoResolveMultipleImports: true,
    },
  ];
}

module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    plugins: ["@babel/transform-react-jsx", createReactCssModulesPlugin()],
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

8 months have passed and you probably know the answer by now, but I'm gonna post my answer anyway.

**SearchBlock/style.scss**

```
.SearchBlock {

  .SettingsIcon {
    margin-right: 7px;
  }
}
```

**SettingsIcon/index.js**

```
const SettingsIcon = (props) => {
  return (
    <svg
      ...
      className='SettingsIcon'
    >
```

This will not work because your class `.SettingsIcon` is in the local scope of your component in `SearchBlock/index.js`

You can either do the styling of `SettingsIcon/index.js` inside it like so:

**SettingsIcon/index.js**

```
import "./style.scss" // style for SettingsIcon

const SettingsIcon = (props) => {
  return (
    <svg
      ...
      styleName='SettingsIcon'
    >
  )
}
```

or pass the class as a prop like so:

**SearchBlock/index.js**

```
import style from "./style.scss"
import { SettingsIcon } from "../../Icons"

<div styleName='SearchBlock'>
 <SettingsIcon size='17' color='#2991F5' extClasses={ style.SettingsIcon }/>
</div>
```

**SettingsIcon/style.scss**

```
.SearchBlock { ... }

.SettingsIcon {
   margin-right: 7px;
}
```

**SettingsIcon/index.js**

```
import "./style.scss" // style for SettingsIcon

const SettingsIcon = (props) => {
  return (
    <svg
    ...
    styleName={ props.extClasses }
    >
  )
}
```